# Segfault after refactoring nested loops

Tags: arrays, c, loops, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I have some MATLAB code from a digital audio course that I've ported to C. Given an array of numeric data (for example, PCM audio encoded as double-precision floating-point), produce an array of data segments of a specified width and which overlap each other by a specified amount. Here's the relevant code.

```
typedef struct AudioFramesDouble {
    const size_t n,   // number of elements in each frame
                 num_frames;
    double* frames[];
} AudioFramesDouble;

/*
 * Produce a doubly-indexed array of overlapping substrings (a.k.a windows, frames,
 * segments ...) from a given array of data.
 *
 * x: array of (i.e., pointer to) data
 * sz: number of data elements to consider
 * n: number of elements in each frame
 * overlap: each frame overlaps the next by a factor of 1 - 1/overlap.
 */
AudioFramesDouble* audio_frames_double(register const double x[], const size_t sz, const unsigned n, const unsigned overlap) {
    // Graceful exit on nullptr
    if (!x) return (void*) x;
    const double hop_d = ((double) n) / ((double) overlap); // Lets us "hop" to the start of the next frame.
    const unsigned hop = (unsigned) ceil(hop_d);
    const unsigned remainder = (unsigned) sz % hop;
    const double num_frames_d = ((double) sz) / hop_d;
    const size_t num_frames = (size_t) (remainder == 0
                            ? floor(num_frames_d) // paranoia about floating point errors
                            : ceil(num_frames_d)); // room for zero-padding
    const size_t total_samples = (size_t) n * num_frames;

    AudioFramesDouble af = {.n = n, .num_frames = num_frames};
    // We want afp->frames to appear as (double*)[num_frames].
    AudioFramesDouble* afp = malloc((sizeof *afp) + (sizeof (double*) * num_frames));
    if (!afp) return afp;
    memcpy(afp, &af, sizeof af);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_frames; ++i) {
        /* Allocate zero-initialized space at the start of each frame. If this
           fails, free up the memory and vomit a null pointer. */
        afp->frames[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
        if (!afp->frames[i]) {
            double* p = afp->frames[i];
            for (long ii = ((long)i) - 1; 0 <= ii; ii--) {
                free(afp->frames[--i]);
            }
            free(afp);
            return (void*) p;
        }

        for (size_t j = 0, k; j < n; ++j) {
            if (sz <= (k = (i*hop) + j)) break;
            afp->frames[i][j] = x[k];
        }
    }

    return afp;
}
```

This performs as expected. I wanted to optimize the nested FOR to the following

```
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0, k; i < num_frames; (j == n - 1) ? (j = 0,i++) : ++j) {
    // If we've reached the end of the frame, reset j to zero.
    // Then allocate the next frame and check for null.
        if (j == 0 && !!(afp->frames[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(double)))) {
            double* p = afp->frames[i];
            for (long ii = ((long)i) - 1; 0 <= ii; ii--) {
                free(afp->frames[--i]);
            }
            free(afp);
            return (void*) p;
        }

        if (sz <= (k = (i*hop) + j)) break;
        afp->frames[i][j] = x[k];
    }
```

This actually compiles and runs just fine; but in my testing, when I try to access the last frame as in
`xFrames->frames[xFrames->num_frames-1]`,
I get a segmentation fault. What's going on here? Am I neglecting an edge case in my loop? I've been looking over the code for awhile, but I might need a second set of eyes. Sorry if the answer is glaringly obvious; I'm a bit of a C novice.

P.S. I'm a fan of branchless programming, so if anyone has tips for cutting out those IFs, I'm all ears. I was using ternary operators before, but reverted to IFs for readability in debugging.

Comment: On a stylistic note: `return (void*) p;` is rather bad! If you want to return a null pointer then `return NULL;` is much better. Attempting to return a null pointer using the wrong type, casted to a generic pointer (for a compiler-generated implicit conversion to `AudioFramesDouble *`) , is rather bad.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the logical operator `&&` and `||` does [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

That means if `j != 0` then you won't actually call `calloc`, and you'll have an invalid pointer in `afp->frames[i]`.

Comment: This is actually the goal, otherwise the i-th pointer would be reset after almost every iteration. Whenever `j == 0`, we either have `i == 0`, or we've just incremented `i`, signifying the start of the next frame.

Comment: @terrygarcia Have you tried stepping through your allocation code using a debugger to see that it really works as intended?

Comment: @terrygarcia The whole code also seems rather complicated, for something that looks like it could be a simple loop calling `malloc` and `memcpy`. Besides the weird return, why loop downward for freeing? There's just no need for that. Save with using the similarly (and therefore confusing) variables `i` and `ii` in that `free` loop. Don't make code more complicated than it needs to be, write simple, clean and readable code to begin with. That will also make it more maintainable for the future.

Comment: I was thinking that it was necessary to free any previously-allocated memory should some allocation fail when `i != 0`. I converted to `long` to allow for a negative value (`ii` read as 'integer `i`') to break the loop, but a one-line `if` would also suffice. I suppose I could just as well iterate upward. All said, I wanted to make an efficient loop with little to no branching or nesting, which admittedly opens the door for obfuscation. Still, I haven't a clue what's going wrong in the last `n` iterations, though I'm guessing the final `calloc` isn't being called.